# Solve the following symmetric equations:

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

Solve the following equations:

\begin{align}\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6 \\
 x_1{}^2+x_2{}^2+x_3{}^2+x_4{}^2=10 \\
 x_1{}^3+x_2{}^3+x_3{}^3+x_4{}^3=18 \\
 x_1{}^4+x_2{}^4+x_3{}^4+x_4{}^4=34 \\
\end{array}
\right.\end{align}

#### method1:

---

consider a polynomial $f(x)$ whose roots are $x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4$

\begin{align}f(x)=x^4+c_1 x^3+c_2 x^2+c_3 x+c_4\end{align}

then $c_1=-6$, $c_2=13$, I'm stuck at how to obtain $c_3$ and $c_4$, ie. $x_1x_2 x_3+ x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4$ and $x_1x_2 x_3 x_4$

---

Are there any other methods? tips?

Comment: Hunt for Vandermonde.

Comment: Use Newton's identities to find the values of the higher order elementary symmetric polynomials.